# Hibernate + JPA 5 - Java Web

Tags: hibernate, aplicação-web, jpa-2.0, glassfish, oracle11g

Estou precisando de uma ajuda no seguinte problema.

Ao executar meu projeto java web em Glassfish o hibernate em toda execução tentar recriar as minhas tabelas.

```
Minha Entity.

@Entity
@Table(name = "Estados")
public class Estado implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "Id_Estado")
private long idEstado;

@Column(name = "Nome", length = 100, nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Column(name = "Sigla", length = 2, nullable = false)
private String sigla;


Meu persistence.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence    
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<!-- oracle -->
<persistence-unit name="oracles" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>Estado</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.68:1521:dbteste"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="teste"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="teste"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <!-- <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO"/> -->
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="10"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="1"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
</properties>
```

O erro que ocorre abaixo. (A tabela já existe no banco de dados, na ultima linha faço uma pesquisa ao qual retorna o valor Rondônia.)

```
Informações:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: oracles...]
Informações:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
Informações:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Informações:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Informações:   HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver at URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.68:1521:dbteste
Informações:   HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=teste, password=****}
Informações:   HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Informações:   MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
Informações:   Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
Informações:   HHH10001007: JDBC isolation level: <unknown>
Informações:   Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@46edde46 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@fdf96dcd [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge12p9u1bevoz21uwg0p0|6c2b1700, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000, initialPoolSize -> 10, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1800, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 10, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@846def9c [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge12p9u1bevoz21uwg0p0|b35b671, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.68:1521:dbteste, properties -> {user=******, password=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge12p9u1bevoz21uwg0p0|619c81d0, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
Informações:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Informações:   HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Informações:   HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@5bd0f576] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Informações:   Hibernate: create table Estados (Id_Estado number(19,0) not null, Nome varchar2(100 char) not null, Sigla varchar2(2 char) not null, primary key (Id_Estado))
WARN:   GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at ConexaoOracle.<init>(ConexaoOracle.java:23)
    at ConexaoOracle.getEntityManager(ConexaoOracle.java:28)
    at ProdutoRosourcesw.getProduto(ProdutoRosourcesw.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: nome já está sendo usado por um objeto existente
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:213)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:37)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:896)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1737)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1692)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:300)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.execute(NewProxyStatement.java:1006)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: Error : 955, Position : 13, Sql = create table Estados (Id_Estado number(19,0) not null, Nome varchar2(100 char) not null, Sigla varchar2(2 char) not null, primary key (Id_Estado)), OriginalSql = create table Estados (Id_Estado number(19,0) not null, Nome varchar2(100 char) not null, Sigla varchar2(2 char) not null, primary key (Id_Estado)), Error Msg = ORA-00955: nome já está sendo usado por um objeto existente
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    ... 85 more

Informações:   Hibernate: select estado0_.Id_Estado as Id_Estado1_0_0_, estado0_.Nome as Nome2_0_0_, estado0_.Sigla as Sigla3_0_0_ from Estados estado0_ where estado0_.Id_Estado=?
Informações:   Rondônia
```

Tenho o mesmo código rodando em um projeto desktop e erro não ocorre.

- Já deletei as tabelas e deixei o sistema recriar novamente pelo hibernate e mesmo assim na próxima execução ele tem causa o mesmo erro.

Comment: Tenta remover a tabela existente e deixa o hibernate criar a tabela.

Comment: Allan, já realizei este procedimento, inclusive criei uma tabela do zero e está ocorrendo o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Você informou Update na propriedade "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" no seu persistence. 
Quando o hibernate foi atualizar as tabelas disparou o erro "nome já está sendo usado por um objeto existente".

O erro está relacionado ao nome do índice da chave primária. Quando o Oracle foi atualizar a tabela, ele não encontrou/usou o índice existente. Tentou criar um novo índice com o mesmo nome e disparou o erro. O Oracle não permite ter dois índices iguais.

Você pode remover a propriedade "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" do persistence e atualizar seu banco manualmente. Nessa situação recomendo que use o Flyway para fazer versionamento do seu banco de dados através de scripts SQL para criar as tabelas.
Ou você pode alterar a propriedade para create-drop, assim o hibernate vai criar as tabelas quando o projeto for executado e quando você parar o servidor o hibernate vai excluir o banco de dados. Assim ele sempre criará o banco de dados do zero evitando o erro.

Se essas soluções não forem viáveis para o seu caso. Leia mais sobre o erro nesse link:
http://eduardolegatti.blogspot.com/2011/11/desvendando-o-erro-ora-00955-durante.html#ixzz5CBktYGNw

Comment: Tiago, eu utilizo as mesmas classes em um projeto desktop e esta situação não ocorre, ou seja ele não tentar recriar as tabelas, a tabela mencionada foi criada pelo próprio Hibernate.

Comment: O projeto desktop se conecta no mesmo banco de dados Oracle?

Comment: Conecta no mesmo banco/usuário e senha além disso utilizo o mesmo persistence.xml